# Fastest way to order by having true result on a left join in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, performance, join, left-join

I am trying to set up something where data is being matched on two different tables. The results would be ordered by some data being true on the second table. However, not everyone in the first table is in the second table. My problem is twofold. 1) Speed. My current MYSQL query takes 4 seconds to go through several thousand results on each table. 2) Not ordering correctly. I need it to order the results by who is online, but still be alphabetical. As it stands now it orders everyone by whether or not they are online according to chathelp table, then fills in the rest with the users table.

What I have:

```
SELECT  u.name, u.id, u.url, c.online
    FROM  users AS u
    LEFT JOIN  livechat AS c ON u.url = CONCAT('http://www.software.com/', c.chat_handle)
    WHERE  u.live_account = 'y'
    ORDER BY  c.online DESC, u.name ASC
    LIMIT  0, 24 

users
+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| id | name        | url                                    | live_account |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------|
|  1 | Lisa Fuller | http://www.software.com/LisaHelpLady | y            |
|  2 | Eric Reiner |                                      | y            |
|  3 | Tom Lansen  | http://www.software.com/SaveUTom     | y            |
|  4 | Billy Bob   | http://www.software.com/BillyBob     | n            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+

chathelp
+------------------------------------+
| chat_id | chat_handle    | online  |
+------------------------------------+
| 12      | LisaHelpLady   | 1       |
| 34      | BillyBob       | 0       |
| 87      | SaveUTom       | 0       |
+------------------------------------+
```

What I would like the data I receive to look like:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name        | id | url                                     | online  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Lisa Fuller |  1 | http://www.software.com/LisaHelpLady    | 1       |
| Eric Reiner |  4 |                                         | 0       |
| Tom Lansen  |  3 | http://www.software.com/SaveUTom        | 0       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Explanation: Billy is excluded right off the bat for not having a live account. Lisa comes before Eric because she is online. Tom comes after Eric because he is offline and alphabetically later in the data. The only matching data between the two tables is a portion of the url column with the chat_handle column.

What I am getting instead:

(basically, I am getting Lisa, Tom, then Eric)

I am getting everybody in the chathelp table listed first whether or not they are online or not. So 600 people come first, then I get the remaining people who aren't in both tables from users table. I need people who are offline in the chathelp table to be sorted into the users table people in alphabetical order. So if Lisa and Tom were the only users online they would come first, but everyone else from the users table regardless of whether or not they set up their chathelp handle would come alphabetically after those two users.

Again, I need to sort them and figure out how to do this in less than 4 seconds. I have tried indexes on both tables, but they don't help. Explain says it is using a key (name) on table users hitting rows 4771 -> Using where;Using temporary; Using filesort and on table2 NULL for key with 1054 rows and nothing in the extra column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit to add table into and explain statement

```
CREATE TABLE `chathelp` (
  `chat_id` int(13) NOT NULL,
  `chat_handle` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `online` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `chat_id` (`chat_id`),
  KEY `chat_handle` (`chat_handle`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 


 CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `live_account` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `livenames` (`live_account`,`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9556 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users      | ref  | livenames     | livenames    | 11      | const | 4771 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | chathelp   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL  | 1144 |                                              |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your query is slow because 1) there is no index on handler can be used , 2) you have an on disk sort either because of the concat or you have  columns in blob type.

Comment: So if I was to add the concat string to the info in chathelp.chat_handle I could do an equal match speeding it up? But then when displaying handles I would have to strip that from the data in MYSQL. Or, create a another column on chathelp with the full URL so that I could match it? Was hoping to avoid having to change anything.

Comment: Okay. Looks like my Friday night is shot. Thanks for your help and I accepted the answer for #2 of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

We're going to guess that `online` is integer datatype.

You can modify the expression in your order by clause like this:

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(online,0) DESC, users.name ASC
         ^^^^^^^      ^^^
```

The problem is that for rows in `user` that don't have a matching row in `chathelp`, the value of the `online` column in the resultset is `NULL`. And `NULL` always sorts after all non-NULL values.

If we assume that a missing row in `helpchat` is to be treated equally with a row in `helpchat` that has a `0` for online, we can replace the NULL value with a `0`. (If there are NULL values in the `online` column, we won't be able to distinguish between that, and a missing row in helpchat (using this expression in the ORDER BY.))

**EDIT**

**Optimizing Performance**

To address performance, we'd need to see the output from `EXPLAIN`.

With the query as its written above, there's no getting around the "Using filesort" to get the rows returned in the order specified, on that expression.

We may be able to re-write the query to get an equivalent result faster.

But I suspect the "Using filesort" operation is not really the problem, unless there's a bloatload (thousands and thousands) of rows to sort.

I suspect that suitable indexes aren't available for the join operation.

But before we go to the knee jerk "*add an index!*", we really need to look at `EXPLAIN`, and look at the table definitions *including* the indexes. (The output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is suitable.

We just don't have enough information to make recommendations yet.

Reference: [**8.8.1 Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html)

As a guess, we might want to try a query like this:

```
 SELECT u.name
      , u.id
      , l.url
      , l.online
   FROM users
   LEFT
   JOIN livechat 
     ON l.url = CONCAT('http://www.software.com/', u.chat_handle)
    AND l.online = 1
  WHERE u.live_account = 'y'
  ORDER 
     BY IF(l.online=1,0,1) ASC 
      , u.name ASC
  LIMIT 0,24
```

After we've added covering indexes, e.g.

```
.. ON user (live_account,chat_handle,name, id)
...ON livechat (url, online)
```

(If query is using a covering index, EXPLAIN should show "Using index" in the Extra column.)

One approach might be to break the query into two parts: an inner join, and a semi-anti join. This is just a guess at something we might try, but again, we'd want to compare the `EXPLAIN` output.

Sometimes, we can get better performance with a pattern like this. But for better performance, both of the queries below are going to need to be more efficient than the original query:

```
 ( SELECT u.name
        , u.id
        , l.url
        , l.online
     FROM users u
     JOIN livechat 
       ON l.url = CONCAT('http://www.software.com/', u.chat_handle)
      AND l.online = 1
    WHERE u.live_account = 'y'
    ORDER 
       BY u.name ASC
    LIMIT 0,24
 )
 UNION ALL
 ( SELECT u.name
        , u.id
        , NULL AS url
        , 0    AS online
     FROM users u
     LEFT
     JOIN livechat 
       ON l.url = CONCAT('http://www.software.com/', u.chat_handle)
      AND l.online = 1
    WHERE l.url IS NULL
      AND u.live_account = 'y'
    ORDER 
       BY u.name ASC
    LIMIT 0,24
 )
 ORDER BY 4 DESC, 1 ASC
 LIMIT 0,24
```

Comment: Yes, online is int value and you have fixed problem #2 in that now it sorts them correctly. But I still have problem one. It takes 4 seconds to run.

Comment: To address performance, we'd need to see the output from `EXPLAIN`. With the query as its written, there's no getting around the "Using filesort" on the expression. But I suspect that's not really the problem, I suspect that suitable indexes aren't available for the join operation. But before we go the knee jerk "add an index", we really need to look at `EXPLAIN`, and the table definitions including indexes (i.e. `SHOW CREATE TABLE`), we don't have enough information yet. Reference: [**8.8.1 Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html)

Comment: Thanks. Rereading what you wrote and using your examples I was able to figure something out that cut the time down.

Comment: I notice that `chatthelp` table is MyISAM engine rather than InnoDB. Is there a specific reason it's not InnoDB?  My suggestion of the two queries with the UNION ALL is premised on the idea that you're only returning the "first 24 rows", so we only need (at most) the "first 24 rows" which have an active chat, and at most, the "first 24 rows" that don't. And my thinking is that we can get MySQL to return rows "in order" using an index, without a need to perform a sort operation on thousands of rows. If we can quickly get 24 rows,and concatenate that with another 24 rows, we can sort that.